# Using CTE inside spark.sql with pyspark - performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to using Spark and I was trying to copy a query from SQL Server 2012 into `spark.sql()` query.
I know that for SQL Server, a CTE is generally preferred over sub-query and that it generally has good performance. My query in SQL Server runs in under 2 minutes. But then I run the same thing in `spark.sql()`, it runs over 15 min before I kill the job.

So do the CTE running inside spark not as efficient as those running inside SQL Server?

Thank you

Comment: you could try breaking out that CTE query and then try to use some spark in built functions to get the job done. It's hard to say how would be able to make it work without sample cte query and the data information.